# How do I access the child rows of an Infragistics Web Grid row?

Tags: infragistics, ultrawebgrid

I need to modify the contents of the child rows of a hierarchical Infragistics web grid when it is expanded. I can get the parent row from "e.Row" in the following code. But how do I get its child rows to edit?

For that matter, how can I get the rows from any band other than band 0?

```
protected void CustomerActivitiesGrid_ExpandRow(object sender, RowEventArgs e)
{
   UltraGridRow expandedRow = e.Row;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's quite easy, just access the row's rows.

```
foreach(UltraGridRow childRow in e.Row.Rows)
{
    // your code
}
```

Subsequently, you can access the children rows of those rows the same way

```
childRow.Rows
```

You can also access a specific row using its key

```
UltraGridRow specificChildRow = e.Row.Rows.FromKey("ChildRowKey");
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks. Do you know how to just get all of the rows form band 1?

Comment: Get the grid control (FindControl(...) or whatever, then just use grid.Rows)